# Saving an HTML file with the URL as the filename in Ruby

Tags: html, ruby, parsing

I'm currently looking for a way to access a URL, save the data as a .html file, and name the file according to the URL. Currently, I have a .text file with each line being an individual URL:

```
http://www.url.com
http://www.url1.com
...
```

My current code is simply saving each .html fi;e as a number, but I'd like to use the names of the URLs themselves if possible.

```
require 'open-uri'

n = 0

open ("urllist.txt"){|o|
    while url = o.gets
        url.chomp!
        printf("URL: %s", url)
        open(url) {|site|
            fname = sprintf("html/%d.html", n)
            open(fname, "w"){|out|
                d=site.read
                out.write(d)
            }
        }
        n += 1
    end 
}
```

Perhaps an option using IO.readlines? I'm not sure.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `URI.parse(url).path` to get the path of a file given a full URL, and then `File.basename(path)` to get just the name of the file itself.

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'uri'

n = 0

open ("urllist.txt"){|o|
    while url = o.gets
        url.chomp!
        printf("URL: %s", url)
        open(url) {|site|
            path = URI.parse(url).path
            fname = "html/#{File.basename(path)}"
            open(fname, "w"){|out|
                d=site.read
                out.write(d)
            }
        }
        n += 1
    end 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there any specific criteria for URL text file for URI.parse(url) to work? At the moment it appears to examine the first URL, but then gives the error: `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:36:in 'initialize': Is a directory - / (Errno::EISDIR)`

Comment: It seems like it's expecting a URL ending in something like `/index.html`, and not just `/`. You should be able to fix this by appending `index.html` (or whatever's appropriate` to the end of URLs ending with `/`.

Comment: Hm, I see. Any suggestions if there's nothing to append? The URLs are simply test examples using things like http://www.sony.com, apple.com, etc. Actually, I just tried it by adding /index.html to one of the URLs that actually has a valid one (apple) and the saved file is an index.html, so not sure how it would deal with multiple URLs, assuming they all had valid /index.html pages.